# HTML5 rotating/animated background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

How would you go about creating something like this

> http://www.bikingboss.com/

(move your mouse horizontally). I just want some general guidelines/ minimal code, where do you get stared, I've learnt *some* HTML5 (diveintohtml5.ep.io), and I was thinking this would have something to do with canvas, am I right?

Comment: Unless you actually want the canvass implementation of these, please remove the the html5 and canvas tags.

Comment: I didn't think I could/someone beat me to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a parallax effect. There is even jQuery plugin for that http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html.

Comment: Good find, it seems likely that the site linked by the OP is actually built with that plugin: `jquery.jparallax.js`

Answer (score 2):

It's not HTML5.

It's a series of elements that overlay each other, each with a different background image, which update position when the mouse moves.

For that page specifically, the element is `UL#parallax`:

```
<ul id="parallax">
    <li id="mountain-1" style="position: absolute; left: 18.498%; margin-left: -332.964px; top: 28.0208%; margin-top: -134.5px;"></li>
    <li id="mountain-2" style="left: 50%; position: absolute; margin-left: -905.494px; top: 28.0208%; margin-top: -134.5px;"></li>
</ul>
```

If you use Firebug, and open this element, you'll see that the `left` and `margin-left` CSS values are updating as you move the mouse.

Comment: Beat me to it. Agreed, not everything that moves and is not flash is html5 :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS `background-position` attribute could probably do all of that. Just set some mouse movement handler with javascript to change the position of background elements (you'd need to have multiple as there are multiple layers of images there).